# Populate javascript var form ASP.NET

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I want to create a auto populate textbox in asp.net. However I am unable to populate the textbox dynamically. Any help would be very appreciated.

Javascript code

```
$( function() {
    var availableTags = [
      "ActionScript",
      "AppleScript",
      "Asp",
      "BASIC",
      "Haskell",
      "Ruby",
      "Scala",
      "Scheme"
    ];
    $( "#tags" ).autocomplete({
      source: availableTags
    });

    $("#disable").click ( function() {

       $( "#tags" ).autocomplete({
        disabled: true
      });

});
    $("#enable").click ( function() {

       $( "#tags" ).autocomplete({
        disabled: false
      });

});

  } );
```

I have tried to populate from asp.net but I am unable to make it work here is  what I have tried.

```
            string[] availableTags = new string[]{
            "Las Vegas",
            "Los Angeles",
            "Tampa",
            "New York",
            "s",
            "sss"
            };

            protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                if (!IsPostBack)
                {
                JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new 

                JavaScriptSerializer();
                    string jsArray = serializer.Serialize(availableTags);
                    this.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), "availableTags", jsArray, true);
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add script tag and use variable with <%= %>

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     var myArray = '<%= jsArray %>';
     console.log(JSON.parse(myArray);
 </script>
```

In your .cs source code note that public before `jsArray`

```
         string[] availableTags = new string[]{
            "Las Vegas",
            "Los Angeles",
            "Tampa",
            "New York",
            "s",
            "sss"
            };
           public string jsArray = string.Empty;
            protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                if (!IsPostBack)
                {
                JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new 

                JavaScriptSerializer();
                jsArray = serializer.Serialize(availableTags);
             }

    }
```

Update script

```
$( function() {
     var myArray = '<%= jsArray %>';
    var availableTags = JSON.parse(myArray);
    $( "#tags" ).autocomplete({
      source: availableTags
    });

    $("#disable").click ( function() {

       $( "#tags" ).autocomplete({
        disabled: true
      });

});
    $("#enable").click ( function() {

       $( "#tags" ).autocomplete({
        disabled: false
      });

});

  } );
```

Comment: I get the following error  the name 'jsArray' does not exist in the current context?

Comment: Thank you that fix that problem however nothing happens when I start typing.                                                                                             var availableTags = '<%= jsArray %>';
      $(function () {
    console.log(JSON.parse(availableTags));
    $( "#tags" ).autocomplete({
      source: availableTags
    });
    
    $("#disable").click ( function() {
 
       $( "#tags" ).autocomplete({
        disabled: true
      });
 
});
    $("#enable").click ( function() {
 
       $( "#tags" ).autocomplete({
        disabled: false
      });
 
});

Comment: I updated answer for script, you need use JSON.parse to array